# Accept JSON payload without root in struts 2

Tags: java, json, apache, struts2, struts2-jquery

We have a requirement to accept post request having the payload without root attribute.

The sample request payload is as :

```
[
    {
        "Id":"test1",
        "Status":"ok"
    },
    {
        "Id":"test2",
        "Status":"ok"
    }
]
```

I have referred the example shown in article : https://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/

It's sending the json object having root element at the top which is working fine. But our requirement is that there will be no root element of the json payload.

I also referred the documentation of 
https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/#wrapping

But it only mentioned that

> "root attribute must be set on the JSONInterceptor when dealing with
>   JSON array."

which I am not able to interpret. Can somebody please help me in this.

Comment: It means you need to configure the interceptor for that action with the name of the array.

Comment: To give you an high level idea, as shown in the reference article the root element in the json is data which gets mapped with the data attribute inside the action. But in my case there is no root element. And the plugin json interceptor is trying to find that root. There it gets failed.

Comment: You need to give it a root, and a setter.

Comment: Can you give a more details info please.